# Implementing internationalization in React application

Tags: javascript, internationalization, reactjs

I am trying to create a react application which should support i18n.. application should support different languages , currency and date formats.. There should be a dropdown with languages and when I select language, it should translate whole application to that specific language.

I have gone through some i18n apis like intl.js and format.js, but I have seen sample translated locales(locale-en.js) already present in sample demo they provided.

I have confused where these translated locales are generating from, do we need to do it manually or api take care of translating whole application.

Please can anyone suggest me on this. How to make my react application to support some languges?

Comment: you might have a look at https://react.i18next.com/